# «Как настоящий берлинец, он чрезвычайно практичен». Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, придаточное-предложение, сравнение

Прошу знающих уточнить принцип постановки или отсутствия запятой в указанном предложении.
С одной стороны, синтаксически это похоже на придаточное причины, то есть обособление обязательно. С другой — старое доброе правило с "в качестве" здесь тоже прослеживается.
Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

***Как настоящий берлинец, он чрезвычайно практичен.***

**Значение причины:** *Так как он настоящий берлинец, он чрезвычайно практичен. Будучи настоящим берлинцем, он чрезвычайно практичен.*

А вот значения "в качестве" **здесь нет**. Скорее можно сказать так: Он не показался мне настоящим берлинцем — для этого он недостаточно практичен.

У Розенталя: https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Сравнительный оборот может содержать в себе оттенок причинного значения: Васенда, как человек положительный и практический, нашёл невыгодным закреплённое место (Пом.) — **будучи** человеком положительным.

Сравнить: ***Это я вам говорю как настоящий берлинец.***   Здесь значение "в качестве".